# Symfony/Doctrine - How to persist an entity while updating the associated entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have these two entities :

**Product.php**

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Shop\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */

class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id" , nullable=false)
    */
    private $category;
```

and **Category.php**

```
class Category
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

So this is a unidirectionnal ManyToOne relationship.

Basically this works like this. Categories are created beforehand.

Then i want to persist my Product `$product`.

- When i do , because of the `cascade={"persist"}` , the Category inside the Product is also persisted.
- But i don't want this to happen.
- So i removed the `cascade={"persist"}` and this happened :
  `a new entity was found through the relationship`

Can you tell me what's wrong ? How can I persist an new Product with a existing category ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? Doctrine obviously doesn't recognize the Category object as a persisted category.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from the fact that my API REST take an Json Object that i unserialize in a Object like this : `$product = $serializer->deserialize($productJson, 'Shop\ProductBundle\Entity\Product', 'json');`

Comment: Doctrine should detect it if the category object has a valid id present. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes it does ... after some research i found an answer that told me that i should use merge instead of persist, what do you know about it ? ( i read the doc, but couldnt understand why i was told this)

Comment: Merging an unserialized entity reinstates it as an entity fully managed by Doctrine. Might do the trick!

Comment: So basically it means that my product that i just deserialize was just not managed ? From the doctrine documentation : `When serializing an entity. The entity retrieved upon subsequent unserialization will be detached` But does this work the same with deserialize from [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) ?